# SQL query: get tags associated with post

Tags: mysql, tags

I have three tables.

```
posts
| id      | title     |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | hello     |
| 2       | goodbye   |
+---------+-----------+

posts_tags
| tag_id  | post_id   |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 1         |
| 2       | 1         |
| 2       | 2         |
+---------+-----------+

tags
| id      | name      |
+---------+-----------+
| 1       | news      |
| 2       | photos    |
+---------+-----------+
```

I want to be able to select the posts, but have this as a result

```
post.id    post.title    tags
------------------------------------
1          hello         news,photos
2          goodbye       photos
```

Something like

```
SELECT *,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) AS tags
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN posts_tags
        ON posts.id = posts_tags.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tags
        ON posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id
```

doesn't seem to work properly. Please advise, thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better will be storing tags additionally in a string right in posts table too to prevent additional joins and grouping. Just as performance denormalization.

Comment: I have multilingual tags so I am kind of forced to normalize the tags.  Do you perhaps have any other suggestions on how I could denormalize? If so, maybe I can start a question on it

Comment: your schema doesn't reflects i18n of tags. did you mean that tag "photo" will be translated into different languages before displaying?


where? in presentation layer? if so - then i don't see any difference between proposal above (with GROUP_CONCAT) and mine. both of them produce list of tags as comma-separated string.


ps: anyway, i think that tags are not appropriate entities to internationalize...

Comment: yea i suppose the tag will be translated. I was hoping to store different translations for each tag in the database if it were to be normalized

Comment: then there is no difference between my proposal with denormalization (that will be fast) and complex query ;-) in both cases you have to explode string into array using "," as separator. meanwhile - it's possible to store serialized array of tags in the "posts.tags" field. in this case all you have to do - is only unserialize it.

Comment: hey zerkms, i ended up going with denormalized tags :) thanks for the recommendation

Comment: @zerkms: i have a doubt. Are you suggesting to use a separate field in `posts` table that will contain tags separate by comma(as a string) and at the same time, another table would be there that will hold `posts_tags_relation` ? My questions is in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10310790/query-for-an-article-tags-associated-with-it

Answer (score 11):

You need to add a `GROUP BY` clause to your query:

```
SELECT posts.*,
       GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name ORDER BY tags.name) AS tags
FROM posts
    LEFT JOIN posts_tags
        ON posts.id = posts_tags.post_id
    LEFT JOIN tags
        ON posts_tags.tag_id = tags.id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

I also added an order to the `GROUP_CONCAT` above to get the tags concatenated in the order you specified.

Comment: I having same issue, once search by tags for example,if I search as a 'news' 'photo' tag is removed instead of should be there, can you please help for same, what i need to do.

Comment: output should be like this : post.id    post.title    tags
------------------------------------
1          hello         news,photos